# Native Auto-Dialers for Smartphones

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

We are trying to create a page that if a mobile user clicks on the URL it automatically fires the native dialer with our telephone number populated. I've gotten as far as having a TFN link appear that would require the mobile user to click to fire the native dialer, but would love to hear ideas on how to code skipping that event and just having the native dialer appear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want on click to actually call instantly?or prompt the user to the dialer with the number you want to call pasted?

Comment: I was thinking "onload", but if you think "onclick" is better I'm all ears (or eyes). Yes, once the mobile user clicks on the URL, we want the native dialer to populate our TFN....

Comment: The latter: "or prompt the user to the dialer with the number you want to call pasted?"